# What is the most efficient logic to .startAt(thisWeek) and .endAt(nextWeek) using moment.js and angularfire?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, momentjs, angularfire

"efficient" is a nice way of saying I can't fathom a good way to do it!

I'm having a tough time figuring out how to set the current week and reference it in a new Firebase record and then go to the previousWeek and nextWeek in the context of the current week.

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://plnkr.firebaseio.com/tasks').startAt(start).endAt(end);
```

This is the reference I am using. startAt() is based on the beginning of the current week, endAt() is 7 days after that. But I can't wrap my head around setting up a new reference to add or remove 7 days from start and end.

Hopefully that at least makes some sense.

Here is the plnkr with the code so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/A8lDKbNvhcSzbWVrysVm?p=preview

Do I need to modify the existing ref somehow? If I make a new ref will that be passed along to the scope properly?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function($firebase, $scope) {


  var populateTasks = function(start, end){
    var ref = new Firebase('https://plnkr.firebaseio.com/tasks').startAt(start).endAt(end);
    var list = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
    $scope.list = list;
  }; 

  //initialize week
  var today = moment();
  var startThisWeek = today.startOf('week').valueOf();
  var endThisWeek = today.startOf('week').add(7, 'd').valueOf(); 
  var thisWeek = today.startOf('week');
  populateTasks(startThisWeek, endThisWeek);

  $scope.currentWeek = startThisWeek;

  var weekInMilli = moment.duration(1, 'weeks').valueOf();

  //set next week
  $scope.nextWeek = function(){
    $scope.currentWeek += weekInMilli;
    var startNextWeek = thisWeek.add(7, 'd').valueOf();
    var endNextWeek = thisWeek.add(14, 'd').valueOf();
    populateTasks(startNextWeek, endNextWeek);
  };
  //set previous week
  $scope.prevWeek = function(){
    $scope.currentWeek -= weekInMilli;
    var startLastWeek = thisWeek.subtract(7, 'd').valueOf();
    var endLastWeek = thisWeek.subtract(14, 'd').valueOf();
    populateTasks(startLastWeek, endLastWeek);
  };

  var last = null;
  $scope.priorityChanged = function(priority) {
    var current = moment(priority).startOf('day');
    var changed = last === null || !last.isSame(current);
    last = current;
    return changed;
  };

  $scope.getDayName = function($priority) {
    return moment($priority).format('dddd');
  };

  $scope.addTask = function(newTask) {
    $scope.list.$add({
      title: newTask.title,
      $priority: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    });
  };

});

//view
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    The current week is {{currentWeek | date}}<br/>
    <button ng-click="prevWeek()">previous week</button>
    <button ng-click="nextWeek()">next week</button>
    <form ng-submit="addTask(task); task.title=null">
      <input placeholder="Add Task" ng-model="task.title"/>
    </form>

    <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-init="changed = priorityChanged(item.$priority)">
     <h3 ng-show="changed">{{getDayName(item.$priority)}}</h3>
     {{item.title}}  
    </li>
```

Comment: Everything here looks pretty solid. I'm not sure what your question is. Are you setting $priority on the "tasks" when they get created? If you set that to a timestamp, you should be all set.

Comment: The solution I have doesn't properly transition between the weeks. I don't see how to modify the new ref and have that reflect when I go through the weeks and add tasks to a different scope of weeks. If you try the plunk the code doesn't actually work.

Comment: Hm, I checked out the plunk :( Looking at [the values for your priorities](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/b17212f0f1213d514d78), they are all on the same day. Nothing would show up for the next week since there are no valid values there. Adding a value adds it for the current timestamp, so I'm still not sure the plunkr explains the problem--it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Sorry @Kato to keep bugging you but I don't think I'm explaining the problem properly. When I click nextWeek() and then click back to prevWeek() it doesn't show the tasks that I originally added. What's the best way to move nextweek() and preWeek() forward and back?

Comment: I think I got it. Now I'm passing in $scope.startThisWeek and modifying that when I pass it into the populateTasks function. Here's the latest plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/A8lDKbNvhcSzbWVrysVm

Comment: I can see that in old revisions of your plunk, but not in the current. In the current, the prev/next [both work nicely](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yy51uu51okdshjx/Untitled.mov?dl=0). Have you resolved it? (oh! I see that you have! yay!)

Comment: @Kato yea, thanks. This might be better asked in a new question (and I will do that after I try a few things) but it seems like my sorting options are now limited. I have to think of a way to add items in reverse and move completed tasks to the bottom. Do you happen to know of any examples?

Comment: You can sort $asArray() lists using list.$watch(list.sort(comparator));

Comment: Thank you @Kato ,that works but it causes a problem when the list sorts. Here is a plunk to help explain the situation: http://plnkr.co/edit/A8lDKbNvhcSzbWVrysVm . The h3 is connected directly to the first list item so if I mark that one as complete or delete it the heading is removed. Is there some way around this?

Comment: Make a new question for that and I'll look at it tonight.

Comment: @Kato Thank you. Very much appreciated. Here is the post(the title isn't quite phrased correctly but I didn't want to make a double post). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047958/is-it-possible-to-sortcompare-and-reverse-an-array-in-angularfire

Answer (score 2):

Here's a plunkr that shows one way of doing it: http://plnkr.co/edit/A8lDKbNvhcSzbWVrysVm

Generally, I initialized the week with a start and end date based on the current week. Then I added those values to $scope. When I needed to go forward or backward a week I would add a weeks worth of time to those values and then pass them back in to the populateTasks function.

```
 //access a range in the array based on the week. My list is sorted by $priority timestamps. 
 var populateTasks = function(start, end) {
    $scope.start = start;
    $scope.end = end;
    var ref = new Firebase('https://plnkr.firebaseio.com/tasks').startAt(start).endAt(end);
    var list = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
    $scope.list = list;
  };

  //initialize the first week
  var setThisWeekStart = moment().startOf('week');
  var setThisWeekEnd = moment().startOf('week').add(7, 'days');
  $scope.startThisWeek = setThisWeekStart.valueOf();
  $scope.endThisWeek = setThisWeekEnd.valueOf();

  //get the tasks for the first week
  populateTasks($scope.startThisWeek, $scope.endThisWeek);

  //a week in milliseconds
  var weekInMilli = moment.duration(1, 'weeks').valueOf();

  //set next week
  $scope.nextWeek = function() {
    $scope.startThisWeek += weekInMilli;
    $scope.endThisWeek += weekInMilli;
    populateTasks($scope.startThisWeek, $scope.endThisWeek);
  };

  //set previous week
  $scope.prevWeek = function() {
    $scope.startThisWeek -= weekInMilli;
    $scope.endThisWeek -= weekInMilli;
    populateTasks($scope.startThisWeek, $scope.endThisWeek);
  };
```

I hope that helps somebody! Thanks to @Kato for his help. He came up with the original solution and set me up for success. Couldn't have done it without him.