# Is it possible to .sort(compare) and .reverse an array in angularfire?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Update: The problem I'm having is doing a combination of three things:

1. Adding a header to an array when the $priority (set to date created) changes. This is so I can group tasks by week and day in an ng-repeat.
2. Resorting that list when a task is checked. Checked tasks should go to the bottom.
3. When creating new tasks, I need to add them to the top of the list instead of the bottom.

Here is a plnkr of all the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/A8lDKbNvhcSzbWVrysVm

I'm using a priorityChanged function to add a header based on comparing the dates on a task: 
      //controller
      var last = null;
      $scope.priorityChanged = function(priority) {
        var current = moment(priority).startOf('day');
        var changed = last === null || !last.isSame(current);
        last = current;
        return changed;
      };

```
//view
<li ng-repeat="task in list track by task.$id">
  <h3 ng-show="priorityChanged(task.$priority)">{{getDayName(task.$priority)}}</h3>
```

and to move a task to the bottom of the list when a task is completed I am using a .sort function when I populate the task list:

```
var populateTasks = function(start, end) {
    $scope.start = start;
    $scope.end = end;
    var ref = new Firebase('https://plnkr.firebaseio.com/tasks').startAt(start).endAt(end);
    var list = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

    list.sort(compare);

    list.$watch(function() {
      list.sort(compare);
    });

    function compare(a, b) {
      return a.completeTime - b.completeTime;
    }

    $scope.list = list;

  };
```

It seems as though these approaches will not work together. Is there a way of combining them so that when the list is re-sorted the ng-repeat will run through the tasks again and add the necessary headers? Is that the ideal solution? Can the header be separate?

Update: I moved the ng-init functionality directly into the h3 to try to get that to run again but it does not display the header in that case.

Update2: The header does seem to show up if at least two of the $priority dates are unique but I still have the problem of deleting or moving the associated list item removing the connected header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**USING A DIRECTIVE**

You can create a directive to simplify things by nesting your client contents. [<kbd>demo</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/qumtENXsVGcdHfMbgv9T?p=preview)

```
app.directive('repeatByWeek', function($parse, $window) {
  return {
    // must be an element called <repeat-by-week />
    restrict: 'E',
    // replace the element with template's contents
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'repeat.html',
    // create an isolate scope so we don't interfere with page
    scope: {
      // an attribute collection="nameOfScopeVariable" must exist
      'master': '=collection'
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      // get the global moment lib
      var moment = $window.moment;
      scope.weeks = [];
      updateList();

      // whenever the source collection changes, update our nested list
      scope.master.$watch(updateList);

      function updateList() {
         scope.weeks = sortItems(parseItems(scope.master));
      }

      function sortItems(sets) {
        var items = [];
        // get a list of weeks and sort them
        var weeks = sortDescending(Object.keys(sets));
         for(var i=0, wlen=weeks.length; i < wlen; i++) {
           var w = weeks[i];
           // get a list of days and sort them
           var days = sortDescending(Object.keys(sets[w]));
           var weekEntry = { 
             time: w, 
             days: []
           };
           items.push(weekEntry);
           // now iterate the days and add entries
           for(var j=0, dlen=days.length; j < dlen; j++) {
             var d = days[j];
             weekEntry.days.push({
               time: d,
               // here is the list of tasks from parseItems
               items: sets[w][d]
             });
           }
         }
         console.log('sortItems', items);
         return items;
      }

      // take the array and nest it in an object by week and then day
      function parseItems(master) {
        var sets = {};
        angular.forEach(master, function(item) {
           var week = moment(item.$priority).startOf('week').valueOf()
           var day = moment(item.$priority).startOf('day').valueOf();
           if( !sets.hasOwnProperty(week) ) {
             sets[week] = {};
           }
           if( !sets[week].hasOwnProperty(day) ) {
             sets[week][day] = [];

           }
           sets[week][day].push(item);
         });
         console.log('parseItems', sets);
         return sets;
      }

      function sortDescending(list) {
        return list.sort().reverse();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The repeat.html template:

```
<ul>
    <!-- 
      it would actually be more elegant to put this content directly in index.html
      so that the view can render it, rather than needing a new directive for
      each variant on this layout; transclude should take care of this but I
      left it out for simplicity (let's slay one dragon at a time)
    -->
    <li ng-repeat="week in weeks">
    <h3>{{week.time | date:"MMMM dd'th'" }}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="day in week.days">
        <h4>{{day.time | date:"MMMM dd'th'" }}</h4>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="task in day.items">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.complete" ng-change="isCompleteTask(task)">
            <input ng-model="task.title" ng-change="updateTask(task)">
            <span ng-click="deleteTask(task)">x</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**OTHER IDEAS**

Most likely, you just need to move your changed out of ng-init. I don't think that is re-run when elements move/resort.

```
<li ng-repeat="task in list">
  <h3 ng-show="priorityChanged(task.$priority)">{{getDayName(task.$priority)}}</h3>
  <!-- ... -->
</li>
```

Since your list may resort several times, you can probably also get a pretty significant speed boost by [using track by](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm)

```
<li ng-repeat="task in list track by task.$id">
```

If that doesn't resolve the problem, it might be time to think about writing your own directive (these are more fun than they sound) and possibly to consider setting aside AngularFire and going right to the source.

You really want a more deeply nested data structure here you can iterate at multiple levels, and you may need to structure that yourself either on the client or the server, now that you have a sense of how you want them organized (essentially a group by week functionality).

Comment: When I move "changed" to inside of the the h3 the heading no longer shows up. Do I need to modify anything in the controller to make that work? (when I add an alert() to the priorityChanged function right before its return the header does show up initially and then it disappears when it reaches the end of the array) I'll work on learning more about actual firebase so that I can transition but it would be great if I could get something working in the short term. Why is a directive better? What would I be able to do that I cannot do now? Thanks and sorry about all the questions. :)

Comment: When there are two unique dates added the headers do show up, but when the list item that includes the header is moved or deleted the view breaks again (header is either in wrong place or removed along with the list item)

Comment: Can you update your fiddle/question with the latest? I'll have a look. A directive is likely better because it's essentially a pluggable module. You can remap the data each time it changes into a more properly nested list, and then call ng-repeat internally in the directive in a nested manner.

Comment: Ok, the fiddle and question are updated. I'm going to watch the egghead.io videos on directives to try to get a better understanding. The goal as I understand it is to run the ng-repeat inside of the directive. Here is the link to the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/A8lDKbNvhcSzbWVrysVm

Comment: Added a working fiddle for you. Took out most of the logic you already have working for simplicity; should work fine with your controller logic for add/update et al.

Comment: Wow, that is amazing. Thank you so much. I'm slowly working through it to try to understand.

Comment: I'm still working through it. I'm trying to add the $scope.deleteTask, $scope.isComplete, etc functions to the controller but it looks like now I don't have access to the scope. Is that one of the the reasons why I need to learn ng-transclude after getting a better handle on this?

Comment: can you please explain your comment about the transclude: <!-- it would actually be more elegant to put this content directly in index.html so that the view can render it, rather than needing a new directive for each variant on this layout; transclude should take care of this but I left it out for simplicity (let's slay one dragon at a time)--> Specifically, would using transclude make everything in the controller available? Is there a similar example you know of that I can reference to try it out? I can't seem to crack it.

Comment: I was able to get transclude working! It's a little bit cleaner this way and easier to connect everything. I'm still researching how to update the ref variable with different start and end dates.

Answer (score 0):

you could use "[unshift](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)" javascript function

```
var fruits = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
fruits.unshift("5","6");
```

Result

```
[ '5', '6', '1', '2', '3', '4' ]
```