# How to set a unique ID for each person in a Firebase database so I can choose which to remove if more than one person have the same name?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'll try to explain this as good as I can.

I'm making a contact book where you can store the following:

First name

Last name

Email

Phone number

There's nothing that prevents you from adding two persons with an identical first and last name, for example Tom Sawyer. 
Now, let's say we have two Tom Sawyer added to the Firebase database, under two random and unique keys generated by the Firebase database. Like this:

[image]

And it's displayed in the HTML like this:

[image: html view of the persons]

When you click on the remove button beside one of the names it should go away both from the HTML and the database. Here's where it gets tricky though, I have no way of telling which Tom Sawyer should be removed from the database, I can't use the unique key names because if I loop through them and search for Tom Sawyer I will get two hits and it will just pick one at random.

My first thought would be to add a second unique ID as a property, but this will just fail in the same way as the unique Firebase key IDs. The unique ID has to be tied to the first and last name added without being randomized (at least the way I see it) so that I can tie the HTML Tom Sawyer to **the** Tom Sawyer in the database. This has to happen **independently** of how many Tom Sawyer that exists in the database or it will not work.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Every time you add a new contact, you set this global variable to point to it: `newChildRef = newChild.name();`. That explains the behavior in your second paragraph. But in general my recommendation would be to put a breakpoint in your `removeFromDb` function and see what the value of `newChildRef` is at that point. Most likely it is not (always) what you expect it to be.

Comment: Hello Chrillewoodz! Welcome to the community. Some thoughts for you, as I can't guess as to cause in the current state of the question: a) there is a reason globals are discouraged b) the value is being set to a key (using .name()) but is referred to as if it contains a ref c) there is a lot of unnecessary code here not related to the problem set and d) there is a lot of missing code necessary to [understand the problem set](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Kato I know what the problem is now, but I still don't know how to resolve it. It basically comes down to the fact that you can have more than one person with the same first and last name in the database, but I don't have a good way of seperating these with a unique ID apart from the key name. Which I can't use to identify which person is who. So until I figure out how to add a unique non-randomized ID there is no solution to my problem, as far as I know.

Comment: Narrow your question to fit the new discoveries and include a small sample of code that can be used to reproduce the scenario, and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @Kato I've revamped the entire question, hopefully it's more clear now. If you wanna help I'd appreciate it big times.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use .key() (.name() before 2.x) to fetch the push id for each record.

### A pojo example (err, +jQuery)

For example, in pojo (with jQuery to abstract the DOM bits):

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
ref.child('contacts').on('child_added', function(snap) {
   var data = snap.val();
   var name = data.first + ' ' + data.last;

   // some proprietary code to add them to the DOM, the critical part 
   // here being that we include the push id in the data...

   // set the push id as data-id so we can refer to it!
   var html = '<li data-id="' + snap.key() + '">' +
       '<span>' + name + '</span> ' +                  // user's name
       '<button data-event="edit">Edit</button> ' +    // edit button
       '<button data-event="delete">Delete</button>' + // delete button
       '</li>';
   $(html).appendTo('#theList');
});

// handle clicking the delete button
$('[data-event="delete"]').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   // fetch the push id from data-id="..." attribute
   var pushId = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-id');

   // remove it from Firebase
   ref.child('contacts').child(pushId).remove();
});
```

### A framework example (Angular)

Of course, a good framework can save you a great deal of energy here. For example, I'm a fan of Angular:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="user in contacts">
     <span>{{user.first}} {{user.last}}</span>
     <button>Edit</button>
     <button ng-click="users.$remove(user)">Delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My Angular controller:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $firebase, $window) {
   var ref = new $window.Firebase(URL);
   $scope.contacts = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
});
```

Comment: Thing is I don't want an ng-repeat on the list items, I display an li for each letter in the alphabet, and then append the names under the corresponding category depending on what the last name starts with. so I'm not sure what I would put in the ng-click with the structure I have?

Comment: That's an entirely different question than how to set a unique id for each person. Entirely, massively different. See this post, which explains how to create a directive with multiple nested layers of data:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047958/is-it-possible-to-sortcompare-and-reverse-an-array-in-angularfire/26051475?noredirect=1#comment40837121_26051475

Answer (score 0):

There you can use firebase with angular js. So that the editing and delete data from firebase is much easier.
Use Firebase.js, then Angular.js and then angularfire.js

```
//In JavaScript File,Initialize angularJs like this

var app=angular.module('YourAppName',[firebase])
//this is dependencies injection you have to do like this

//get the firebase URL and store it like this

var fb_url=new Firebase('Your Firebase database URL') 
//then store it in $scope variable i.e 

$scope.data=$firebaseArray(fb_url)

//In Html file,

<div>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="da in data">
<td>{{da.name}} </td>
<td>{{da.age}} </td>
<td><input type="button" value="Edit" ng-click="EditBtn(da)"/></td>
<td><input type="button" value="delete" ng-click="DelBtn(da)"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
//In Javascript File,

$scope.EditBtn=function(da){
$scope.Name=da.name;
$scope.age=da.age;
$scope.id=da.$id;
//this is unique id which generated when you insert the data.
}
//In Html

<div>
<input type="text" ng-model="Name"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="age"/>
<input type="button" value="Save Edit" ng-click="SaveEdit()"/>
</div>

//In Js file    

$scope.SaveEdit=function(){
var Id=$scope.id;
var record=$scope.data.$getRecord(Id);
record.name=$scope.Name;
record.age=$scope.Age;
$scope.data.$save(record);
}

$scope.DelBtn=function(da){
$scope.data.$remove(da);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an easier solution ? It is pretty heavy-handed to add Angular just to get the unique ID of entries.

Comment: Hi Demurugos . This is the simplest way to do it in angularfire

Comment: But he did not mention Angularfire nor Angular